# In Applescript, how do I pass (or prompt) password within do shell script for psql?

Tags: shell, applescript, psql

To clarify, I'm not talking about my administrative credentials. I'm specifically talking about db credentials.

If I run this script like this in terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/psql -h my-db -U userName test -Atc 'SELECT id, title, internal_name FROM my.template WHERE my_id = 5'
```

...it works fine.

But in Applescript:

```
set myInfo to do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/psql -h my-db -U userName test -Atc 'SELECT id, title, internal_name FROM my.template WHERE my_id = 5'")
```

...it spits out "psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Thanks

Comment: When you run the psql command in terminal, does it prompt you for a pw? Have you checked the man page to see the syntax for including the password?

Comment: Yes, it does prompt for a password when I run it in terminal. In Applescript, the script fails with some error about 'no password provided'. I have heard it's possible to use a  ~/.pgpass but I'm not sure how to pass that in applescript

Comment: If you find the syntax in the man page for passing the pw, we can figure it out in AS.

Comment: I don't know what the 'man page' is. sorry

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in terminal if you don't know what a man page is. The Manual page. Read the […] Manual to find out the syntax of the psql command that includes password, if there is one.

Comment: Wow, the funny thing is the question you're asking is really the same question I'm asking. But you worded your response in such a way that I was able to find an answer online (unfortunately, not in the man page)!  All I have to do in the shell script is add this to the beginning: 'PGPASSWORD=myPassword'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the beginning of the shell script: 'PGPASSWORD=myPassword'